# How to display all events that a user is assigned to, using Fullcalendar Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, fullcalendar

So this is my current model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_and_belongs_to_many :event_series
 has_many :events, through: :event_series
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :event_series
end

class EventSeries < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_and_belongs_to_many :users
 has_many :events
end

class UserEventSeries < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :event
 belongs_to :user
end
```

So a user gets assigned to an event series, and each event series has many events. When the user signs in and visits their user dashboard I want to use Fullcalendar to display all of the events that the signed in user is currently assigned to.

I am able to get all of the user's events and have made a JSON using jbuilder which currently retrieves all of the user's events. However, the events do not show on the calendar(located on http://localhost:3000/users/1).

JSON on http://localhost:3000/users/1.json:

```
{
"events": [{
    "all_day": false,
    "created_at": "2017-04-06T14:16:24-05:00",
    "description": "sdsdsdsdsdd",
    "endtime": "2017-04-06T15:16:00-05:00",
    "event_series_id": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "starttime": "2017-04-06T14:16:00-05:00",
    "title": "title",
    "updated_at": "2017-04-06T14:16:24-05:00"
}, {
    "all_day": false,
    "created_at": "2017-04-06T14:16:24-05:00",
    "description": "sdsdsdsdsdd",
    "endtime": "2017-04-13T15:16:00-05:00",
    "event_series_id": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "starttime": "2017-04-13T14:16:00-05:00",
    "title": "title",
    "updated_at": "2017-04-06T14:16:24-05:00"
}, {
    "all_day": false,
    "created_at": "2017-04-06T14:16:24-05:00",
    "description": "sdsdsdsdsdd",
    "endtime": "2017-04-20T15:16:00-05:00",
    "event_series_id": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "starttime": "2017-04-20T14:16:00-05:00",
    "title": "title",
    "updated_at": "2017-04-06T14:16:24-05:00"
}, {
    "all_day": false,
    "created_at": "2017-04-06T14:16:24-05:00",
    "description": "sdsdsdsdsdd",
    "endtime": "2017-04-27T15:16:00-05:00",
    "event_series_id": 1,
    "id": 4,
    "starttime": "2017-04-27T14:16:00-05:00",
    "title": "title",
    "updated_at": "2017-04-06T14:16:24-05:00"
}, {
    "all_day": false,
    "created_at": "2017-04-06T14:16:24-05:00",
    "description": "sdsdsdsdsdd",
    "endtime": "2017-05-04T15:16:00-05:00",
    "event_series_id": 1,
    "id": 5,
    "starttime": "2017-05-04T14:16:00-05:00",
    "title": "title",
    "updated_at": "2017-04-06T14:16:24-05:00"
}, {
    "all_day": false,
    "created_at": "2017-04-06T14:16:24-05:00",
    "description": "sdsdsdsdsdd",
    "endtime": "2017-05-11T15:16:00-05:00",
    "event_series_id": 1,
    "id": 6,
    "starttime": "2017-05-11T14:16:00-05:00",
    "title": "title",
    "updated_at": "2017-04-06T14:16:24-05:00"
}, {
    "all_day": false,
    "created_at": "2017-04-06T14:16:24-05:00",
    "description": "sdsdsdsdsdd",
    "endtime": "2017-05-18T15:16:00-05:00",
    "event_series_id": 1,
    "id": 7,
    "starttime": "2017-05-18T14:16:00-05:00",
    "title": "title",
    "updated_at": "2017-04-06T14:16:24-05:00"
}, {
    "all_day": false,
    "created_at": "2017-04-06T14:16:24-05:00",
    "description": "sdsdsdsdsdd",
    "endtime": "2017-05-25T15:16:00-05:00",
    "event_series_id": 1,
    "id": 8,
    "starttime": "2017-05-25T14:16:00-05:00",
    "title": "title",
    "updated_at": "2017-04-06T14:16:24-05:00"
}, {
    "all_day": false,
    "created_at": "2017-04-06T14:16:24-05:00",
    "description": "sdsdsdsdsdd",
    "endtime": "2017-06-01T15:16:00-05:00",
    "event_series_id": 1,
    "id": 9,
    "starttime": "2017-06-01T14:16:00-05:00",
    "title": "title",
    "updated_at": "2017-04-06T14:16:24-05:00"
}, {
    "all_day": false,
    "created_at": "2017-04-06T14:16:24-05:00",
    "description": "sdsdsdsdsdd",
    "endtime": "2017-06-08T15:16:00-05:00",
    "event_series_id": 1,
    "id": 10,
    "starttime": "2017-06-08T14:16:00-05:00",
    "title": "title",
    "updated_at": "2017-04-06T14:16:24-05:00"
}, {
    "all_day": false,
    "created_at": "2017-04-06T14:16:24-05:00",
    "description": "sdsdsdsdsdd",
    "endtime": "2017-06-15T15:16:00-05:00",
    "event_series_id": 1,
    "id": 11,
    "starttime": "2017-06-15T14:16:00-05:00",
    "title": "title",
    "updated_at": "2017-04-06T14:16:24-05:00"
}, {
    "all_day": false,
    "created_at": "2017-04-06T14:16:24-05:00",
    "description": "sdsdsdsdsdd",
    "endtime": "2017-06-22T15:16:00-05:00",
    "event_series_id": 1,
    "id": 12,
    "starttime": "2017-06-22T14:16:00-05:00",
    "title": "title",
    "updated_at": "2017-04-06T14:16:24-05:00"
}, {
    "all_day": false,
    "created_at": "2017-04-06T14:16:24-05:00",
    "description": "sdsdsdsdsdd",
    "endtime": "2017-06-29T15:16:00-05:00",
    "event_series_id": 1,
    "id": 13,
    "starttime": "2017-06-29T14:16:00-05:00",
    "title": "title",
    "updated_at": "2017-04-06T14:16:24-05:00"
}, {
    "all_day": false,
    "created_at": "2017-04-06T14:16:24-05:00",
    "description": "sdsdsdsdsdd",
    "endtime": "2017-07-06T15:16:00-05:00",
    "event_series_id": 1,
    "id": 14,
    "starttime": "2017-07-06T14:16:00-05:00",
    "title": "title",
    "updated_at": "2017-04-06T14:16:24-05:00"
}, {
    "all_day": false,
    "created_at": "2017-04-06T14:16:24-05:00",
    "description": "sdsdsdsdsdd",
    "endtime": "2017-07-13T15:16:00-05:00",
    "event_series_id": 1,
    "id": 15,
    "starttime": "2017-07-13T14:16:00-05:00",
    "title": "title",
    "updated_at": "2017-04-06T14:16:24-05:00"
}, {
    "all_day": false,
    "created_at": "2017-04-06T14:16:24-05:00",
    "description": "sdsdsdsdsdd",
    "endtime": "2017-07-20T15:16:00-05:00",
    "event_series_id": 1,
    "id": 16,
    "starttime": "2017-07-20T14:16:00-05:00",
    "title": "title",
    "updated_at": "2017-04-06T14:16:24-05:00"
}, {...and so on
```

Jbuilder: show.json.jbuilder

```
json.events @user.events
```

And Finally The Fullcalendar Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    editable: false,
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    height: 500,
    slotMinutes: 15,
    events: "/users/1.json",
    timeFormat: 'h:mm t{ - h:mm t} ',
    dragOpacity: "0.5",
    eventClick:  function(event, jsEvent, view) {
      $('#modalTitle').html(event.title);
      $('#modalBody').html(event.description);
      $('#eventUrl').attr('href',event.url);
      $('#fullCalModal').modal();
    },
  });
});
```

Comment: you forgot to use `eventRender` method to display events in respective date.

Answer (score 0):

A good practice would be to debug using callback methods.

Could you try the following and see if this is giving you the expected return?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    editable: false,
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    height: 500,
    slotMinutes: 15,
    eventSources: [
      {
        url: '/users/1.json',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (response) {
          console.log(response);
        }
        error: function(response) {
          console.log(response);
        }
      }
    ]
    // events: "/users/1.json",
    timeFormat: 'h:mm t{ - h:mm t} ',
    dragOpacity: "0.5",
    eventClick:  function(event, jsEvent, view) {
      $('#modalTitle').html(event.title);
      $('#modalBody').html(event.description);
      $('#eventUrl').attr('href',event.url);
      $('#fullCalModal').modal();
    },
  });
});
```

If the expected data is being output in the console, then the problem is not your Rails backend.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON format was incorrect so I changed the jbuilder file to:

```
json.array! @user.events do |event|
  date_format = event.all_day? ? '%Y-%m-%d' : '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'
  json.id event.id
  json.title event.title
  json.start event.starttime.strftime(date_format)
  json.end event.endtime.strftime(date_format)

  json.allDay event.all_day? ? true : false
  json.update_url event_path(event, method: :patch)
  json.edit_url edit_event_path(event)
end
```